# The question is to find the sum of 2 consecutive numbers in the list x that equals to t and return x list without the second number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def trouble(x, t):
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
      
      if (x[i]+ x[i+1]) == t:
        return x
      
      else:
        return None

answer = trouble([4,5,6,7], 9)
print(answer)
```

Comment: It's very difficult to follow what your question is and what you are trying to achieve. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it easier to assist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this that you want done. It removes the second value that adds up to t. And returns that new list.

```
def trouble(x, t):
    x = list(x)
    for i in range(0, len(x)-1):
        if (x[i]+ x[i+1]) == t:
            y = list(x) 
            y.pop(i+1)
            return y
        
      
    else:
        return None

answer = trouble([1,3,6], 9)
print(answer)
```

Comment: This just doesn't work. This code can only find a solution if it's the sum of the first two numbers of the list. `print(trouble([3, 4, 6, 3], 9))` outputs `None`...

Comment: @Tresha Accepting wrong answers could lead other users to erroneously think that the code in the answer is working. Please note that you have time to check, and accept an answer if it is valid and effectively answers your question.

Comment: Please check the test case in my comment.

Comment: The output in my comment is not my interpretation of the code, but the real output I got by actually running it.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. It's easy to find a test case like `answer = trouble([1, 3, 6], 9)`. It outputs `IndexError: pop index out of range`.

Comment: No, you didn't, and trying to hide exceptions caused by logic errors in your code can't make it right. It now outputs `None`, while the correct, expected output is `[1, 3]`. Please always take the time to thoroughly test your code **before** posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's not quite clear what you're actually asking, you just shoved a code blob and a title. Assuming you want someone to tell you if your code is correct; it is not.
Now this really just looks like a homework problem, so I won't just post an answer code blob, but here are some comments that might be useful:

```
def trouble(x, t):
    for i in range(0,len(x)): # Range starts at 0 even when not specified
      
      if (x[i]+ x[i+1]) == t:
        return x  
        # You also want to remove the second number no ? 
        # Hint: you could use slicing, or the list remove(elem) function
      
      else:
        # Because this is in the loop it will return immediately
        # if the if condition fails (ie: you'll only ever
        # look at the first element !

        return None 

answer = trouble([4,5,6,7], 9)
print(answer)
```

Comment: Using `remove` will remove the first instance of a number in the list, which might not be the right one if there are duplicates.